# Buttons with multiline text sink under alignment line, how to fix it?

Tags: android, layout, button, alignment, multiline

I see strange behavior of simple buttons, when their text splits on several lines. I have it in more complex situation, but even in the simplest one it happens. With this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="70dip" android:text="111" />
<Button android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="70dip" android:text="111 222 333" />
<Button android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="70dip" android:text="111 222 333 444 555 666" />
<Button android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="70dip" android:text="111" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the result is: [image: buttons not in a row]

Buttons go down and down with every next line of text. I want them in a line. Is this an android bug and how to fix it?

Comment: Its not a bug, the buttons' text baseline is aligned with other buttons. Setting `baselineAligned` to `false` of `LinearLayout` will fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="111" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="111 222 333" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="111 222 333 444 555 666" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="111" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: +1. Thanks! Actually android:layout_gravity="center" for buttons seems to be enought, no need from nested activities. I will wait some more hours for other opinions, but probably your answer will get the points.

Comment: android:gravity="center" as layout property works too, with some other conditions like:
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">

Answer (score 3):

Set LinearLayout's `android:baselineAligned` to `false`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:text="111" />

<Button
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:text="111 222 333" />

<Button
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn2"
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:text="111 222 333 444 555 666" />

<Button
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn3"
    android:id="@+id/btn4"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:text="111" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1. This works, but android:layout_gravity="center" from dmytrodanylyk solution is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

in place of buttons use like this

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="111" />
```

Comment: I want these buttons to be with equal size. Actually I use android:layout_weight="1" and android:layout_width="0dip" in my real program, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Use below 2 lines in every button, then all buttons will come in single line.

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

If you want these buttons has to stretch the entire width add below line also to every button

```
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: I know what "wrap_content" does, but I want buttons with equal size.